# Angular weather-application failed to compile

Tags: angular, weather

This is my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {WeatherListComponent} from './weather/weather-list.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: '
        <header> 
            <h1> Ang app</h1>
        </header>
        <weather-list></weather-list>
    ',
    styleUrls:[''src/css/weater-item.css]
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'weather';
}
```

This is my weather-list.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular/core';
import {WeatherItemComponent} from './weather-item.component';
import {WeatherItem} from './weather-item';
import {WeatherService} from './weather-service';

@Component({
    selector: 'weather-list',
    template:`
        <section class='weather-list'>
            <weather-item>*ngFor='#weatherItem of 
            weatherItems'[item]='weatherItem'</weather-item>
        </section>`,

    directives:  [WeatherItemComponent],
    providers:[WeatherService]
})
export class WeatherListComponent implements onInit {
    weatherItems:WeatherItem[];

    constructor(private_weatherService: WeatherService){}

    ngOnInit():any {
        this.weatherItems= this._weatherService.getWeatherItems();
    }   
}
```

This is my weather-item.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'weather-item',
    template: `
        <article class='weather-element'>
            <div class='col-1'>
                <h3>{{weatherItem.cityName}}</h3>
                <p class='info'>{{weather.description}}</p>
            </div>
            <divclass='col-2'>
                <span class='temperature'>{{weather.temperature}}</span>
            </div>
        </article>
        `,
    styleUrls=['src/css/weather-item.css'],
    inputs:['weatherItem: item']
})

export class WeatherItemComponent { 
    weatherItem: Weather;

    constructor(){
        this.weatherItem= new WeatherItem('London'.'RAINY',32);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what mistake i made it failed to compile with a lot of errors, for example:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(4,2): 
>         error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 4.
>         src/app/app.component.ts(4,12): error TS2362: The left-hand side of an 
>        arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum     type
>        src/app/app.component.ts(4,12): error TS2365: Operator '<' cannot be 
>        applied 
>           src/app/app.component.ts(7,5): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'header'. 
>            Did you mean 'Headers'?
>           src/app/app.component.ts(8,6): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'h1'.
>           src/app/app.component.ts(8,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Ang'.
>           src/app/app.component.ts(10,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 
>           'weather'.
>           src/app/app.component.ts(10,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'list'.
>           src/app/app.component.ts(12,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 
>          'styleUrls'

Comment: Improved Code Formatting for better readability

Comment: Have you found some answer helpful?

Comment: Then please mark answer that helped you as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong in your app.component

```
styleUrls:[''src/css/weater-item.css]
```

Looks like you pasted it and missed the target between the ' '.

And try to use ` instead of ' when doing multi line strings, like you did here:

```
template: '
                <header> 
                    <h1> Ang app</h1>
                </header>
                <weather-list></weather-list>
              '
```

Answer (score 0):

According to those errors the problem is in you template in `AppComponent` because string can't be used while you are wrapping the content.

You need to put the template into `template literal`. You also have a mistake in `styleUrls`

```
template: ` <header> 
             <h1> Ang app</h1>
            </header>
            <weather-list></weather-list>`,
styleUrls: ['src/css/weater-item.css']
```